# How to iterate the value in component.find lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

In my parent controller i have the following code.

```
 var name = component.find("towermid");
    console.log("name"+name);
   //component.set("v.isReadOnly","true");
```

This console name returns:

```
 name:SecureComponent: markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal {8:69;a} {towermid}{ key: 
{"namespace":"c"} },SecureComponent: markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal {16:69;a} 
{towermid}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} },SecureComponent: markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal 
{24:69;a} {towermid}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} },SecureComponent: 
markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal {32:69;a} {towermid}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} 
},SecureComponent: markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal {40:69;a} {towermid}{ key: 
{"namespace":"c"} },SecureComponent: markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal {48:69;a} 
{towermid}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} },SecureComponent: markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal 
{72:69;a} {towermid}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} },SecureComponent: 
markup://c:GE_REN_GetVal {94:69;a} {towermid}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
```

Child Component:
**GE_REN_GetVal**

```
<lightning:input                       
                                             aura:id="childid"
                                             name="{!v.fl.FieldName}"
                                             type="{!v.fl.DataType}"
                                             value="{!v.Val}"
                                             onchange="{!c.putDataInOli}"
                                             checked="{!v.Val}"
                                             disabled="{!v.isReadOnly}"
                                             />
```

How to iterate the name and get the child component details in my parent controller?

I want to disable a particular component in the child from the details which I get from the **name**.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what details you are trying to read about the child component or what you are going to do with the child component??

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are not allowed in aura:id.

```
aura:id="{!v.fl.FieldName}"
```

... defines the ID `{!v.fl.FieldName}`, not whatever was in the value for FieldName. You must use a hard-coded string.

However, this won't help your direct problem. You cannot reach into a component to get its child components. Instead, you can access the attribute `Val` (assuming it is access="public" and in your namespace, or access="global" and in any namespace).

```
var inputs = component.find("towermid").map(cmp=>({ field: cmp.get("v.fl.FieldName"), value: cmp.get("v.Val") }));
// Should output as:
// [ { field: "Field1", value: "Hello" },{ field: "Field2", value: "World" } ]
```

Comment: I have used hardcoded aura id. But in parent component still I am getting the above response(modified). My intention is to disable particular child component from the parent.

Comment: @SandraRobert you can't reach the inner components of the child component. Use the parent's `isReadOnly` attribute to control if the field is read-only.

Comment: Thanks , now I am getting the values using the above code(lesson learnt). As you said we cant control the inner components, I have used component.set("v.isReadOnly",name); in my parent. Its not working!!

Comment: @SandraRobert You would set the isReadOnly attribute on the child components.

Comment: Thanks, Now I am able to disable using isReadOnly = true, after that when i set isReadOnly = false  its not editable. Still i see Readonly attribue in lightning:input but the value which we passed is false.